# How to check whether the Android application is turned off?

Tags: android

I want to check whether the application is COMPLETELY off - not in the background, just whether it is turned off.

I thought about using for background the `onResume` etc. options, and for "turned off" task Manager or something...

Comment: I don't see how this would be possible. If the app is not running at all, then there is no code executing.  If any code at all is being executed, then the app is running.

Comment: What, in precise computer programming terms, does it mean for an app to be "turned off"?

Comment: @anzaidemirzoi A service is defined within the context of an app, so would that be considered the app being "off" if it had a background service?

Comment: Hard for me to say whether the Listeners in Android work when the app is onStop.

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz have you checked my answer below is it helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called App is turned off!

for any Application to not be running anymore, it means that the method

```
onStop()
```

has been called on all of it's activities.

See [Activity life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)